# Javascript if statement in append string checking if object property is undefined if not display property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, append

This javascript outputs a few object properties using append

```
d.addClass("has-caption")
 .append(g('<span class="caption" />')
 .html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">' + b.category + '</div>' + '<div class="client">' + b.client + '</div>'));
```

On my site if `b.category` and `b.client` are not defined they show up as undefined. So I tried adding an if statement to check if these properties were basically empty or had a value with this if statement added checking if `b.category` was not undefined.

```
d.addClass("has-caption")
 .append(g('<span class="caption" />')
 .html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">'if (typeof b.category !=== "undefined") { +b.category+} '</div>' + '<div class="client">' + b.client + '</div>'));
```

I thought maybe the if statement could check if `b.category` was not undefined to display it otherwise don't output that property.

This clearly doesn't work, and my javascript knowledge isn't very good so how can I use that if statement to check if the properties or not undefined and if so display them otherwise don't output them while still using append and the same string as in my code?

Comment: See the [Conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can express this with a ternary operator:

```
.html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">' + (typeof b.category !== "undefined" ? b.category : '') +
   '</div>' + etc
```

or in a more fancy way with the boolean "or":

```
.html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">' + (b.category || '') +
   '</div>' + etc
```

(the latter assumes `b.category` can't be `0`).

although I personally would prefer to write (find) a dedicated formatting function:

```
.html("{caption} <div class='cat'>{category}</div> <div class='client'>{client}</div>".format(b))
```

The simplest possible implementation of `format` could be like this:

```
String.prototype.format = function(props) {
    return this.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(_, key) {
        return key in props ? props[key] : "";
    })
}
```

Example:

```
b = {
    foo: 123
}

console.log("hi {foo} and {bar}!".format(b))
// hi 123 and !
```

Answer (score 2):

Build your string piece by piece, then append it:

```
var str = b.caption;
if (typeof b.category != "undefined") {
    str += '<div class="cat">' + b.category + '</div>';
}
str += '<div class="client">' + b.client + '</div>';
str += '</span>'; // note, it seems you missed that part.

d.addClass("has-caption")
 .append(g('<span class="caption" />')
 .html(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're OK with still showing the `<div class="client">` even if there is no client, you can use the `||` operator to replace "falsy" values, like undefined properties, with an empty string:

```
d.addClass("has-caption")
 .append(g('<span class="caption" />')
 .html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">' + (b.category||'') + '</div>' + '<div class="client">' + (b.client||'') + '</div>'))
```

To do the exact same thing as in your sample, you can use `?:` for excluding the second div:

```
d.addClass("has-caption")
 .append(g('<span class="caption" />')
 .html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">' + (b.category||'') + '</div>' + (d.client ? '<div class="client">' + b.client + '</div>') : ''))
```

I'd discourage such long one-liners, myself. If you built your HTML as a variable, your code would be much easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Do it before the actual line of code :

```
b.category = typeof b.category !== "undefined" ? b.category : ''; 
d.addClass("has-caption")
 .append(g('<span class="caption" />')
 .html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">' +b.category+ '</div>' + '<div class="client">' + b.client + '</div>'));
```

If you dont want to alter the object, save it in a var :

```
var t = typeof b.category !== "undefined" ? b.category : ''; 
d.addClass("has-caption")
 .append(g('<span class="caption" />')
 .html(b.caption + '<div class="cat">' +t+ '</div>' + '<div class="client">' + b.client + '</div>'));
```